# Fedora 38 Failing To Boot With NVIDIA Drivers After Software Update

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, nvidia, boot-loader, proprietary-drivers

I have had Nvidia drivers working on fedora for a while with secure boot. For some reason, after a software update the other day, I have had difficulty booting. I noticed after looking at the output log while booting that it got stuck on `NetworkManager-dispatch.service`. But after disabling it, it got stuck on `gdm.service` (GNOME Desktop Manager). It seemed when I got rid of the boot parameter `rhgb quite`, to get stuck on something to do with networking, but had warnings about the NVIDIA device. I removed all the GRUB 2 boot parameters (sans kernel spec) and it booted (second monitor now shows white or flickers in/out of white on half the screen). Its boot able now but would like to use the NVIDIA card. Here are the parameters:

```
rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1 initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init rhgb quiet initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1
```

I tried removing different combinations of these parameters, but the best I seem to be able t do is boot with no NVIDIA driver.

Lots of these seem duplicated, I am not sure if that may have anything to do with it, there was a post on [NVIDIA forums I saw with regard to this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-gpu-fails-to-detect-display-monitor-freezing-at-nvidia-persistence-daemon-debian-rtx-a4000/272460), I tried something similar but it did not seem to help.

Any ideas or steps I should take next?

It seems to randomly work all the sudden every around every 10 boots or so, either with unmodified boot parameters, or with modified ones, I don't know why. I have tried repeating the same boot parameters, and it doesn't work.

So sometimes it boots with the NVIDIA driver working, but most of the time not, and I dont know how to control it or what causes this.